# Touching a view that's always on screen

Tags: android, android-view, android-event

I have a view that's always on the screen (over other apps), I wan't to receive touch events and than to  pass them farther.

The code from the running `Service` :

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,  
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "view touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    WindowManager localWindowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService("window");
    localWindowManager.addView(v, localLayoutParams);
```

currently I don't get the touches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to declare your view as `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`, as below:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params =
        new WindowManager.LayoutParams(width, height, x, y,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
```

This way it will only respond to touches on the view itself.

This code comes from a working task-switcher that I designed. I did not use `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` as it caused problems for me when interacting with other windows below my overlay.

---

As far as passing the touches on to other apps - that is no longer possible, as it represents a security risk.

I recently put a few more details together on a similar question, which you might find interesting to read:

- [Background app to listen to Drag gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25809516/383414)

Also an interesting library [mentioned by Edward Jezisek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25813539/383414) is StandOut by pingpongboss:

- ["StandOut - Create Floating Apps" on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531)
- [StandOut on github](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut/tree/master/library/src/wei/mark/standout)

Since it is open source, you can go through the code to figure out what he is doing.

Comment: I still don't get the `onTouch` event... and I was able to interact  with other apps when I used the `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` flag

Comment: sorry I had a touch listener in another place,   that wasn't passing the event further.<br/> currently I'm trying to overcome the issue of passing the event to the views under mine (that aren't mine). As I understood from your answer I cannot do this. so I'm trying to find a way to simulate a touch event to the system

Comment: There is no solution in the apps you've mentioned, as it's only deals with touch events on it's view and doesn't pass them further.

Comment: @RCB Just added those for future readers as it is useful information. As for passing events further - as I said, it is not (should not be) possible without root.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` makes your view not-touchable.

Use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE` instead.

**UPDATE:**

I forgot one thing.
If you set only `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE`, other app's `View` will not be touched. So add `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` flag surely.